# Image not showing in pop-up (CSS,HTML,Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am building a website and I am running into a problem. I am fairly new to the world of CSS, HTML, Javascript so perhaps this is a no brainer for most of you but I face the following problem. 
I would like to have an image in a pop-up, however the image is not showing (called 'ErrorImage' in the snippet). I've checked whether the file-path of the image is correct, and it is. Please view the snippets below. Any help?

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
    opacity: 0.98;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
    <a title="More about us">
        <img src="About.JPG" alt="About">
    </a>
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img src="ErrorImage.JPG"<
        <p>Example text</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you link image correctly ?

Comment: Are you sure about the path? Try ./ErrorImage.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was showing but your left was -50% that is why it was going out of the screen. i have adjusted it accordingly so it shows on the screen. hope this helps. thanks

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 0.98;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
            <a title="More about us">
                               about
            </a>
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><p>Example text</p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It was a tiny thing but it helped! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's working but your image is off screen. Just make a few changes in your CSS:

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.98;
  text-align: justify;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
            <a title="More about us">
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=About-Image&w=350&h=250" alt="About">
            </a>
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Error-Image&w=350&h=250"><p>Example text</p></span>
</div>
```